# Why does my git push hang after successfully pushing?

Tags: git

On a newly set up ssh git repo, whenever I push, I get normal output like this:

```
➔ git push
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 989 bytes, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

It happens very quickly, and the changes are immediately available on the server repo. But the output hangs there for about a minute, and then finishes with:

```
To foo@bar.com:baz.git
   c8c391c..1de5e80  branch_name -> branch_name
```

If I control-c before it finishes, everything seems to continue to be normal and healthy, locally and remotely.

What is it doing while hanging? Is something configured incorrectly on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Check your virus scanner. Git potentially works on a lot of files. Before they are available to any process already running on the machine (ie, a git pull), they may be blocked by the anti-virus program. Once the scan in complete, it will release the files and the update of branch file will finish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, no virus scanner. Also I have an SSD, so I can't imagine that anything involving local disc access is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The server side could be running hooks that delay the completion for some reason—like company scripts checking what you pushed actually compiles..

Comment: It's a pretty simple setup, but I'll ask if there are any hooks, thanks.